# "Access is denied" warning message when trying to view C:\Users\All Users\Desktop

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, desktop, file-management

When I try to access `C:\Users\All Users\Desktop`, it gives me "Access is denied", even though I'm using an administrator account.

So what I did was I right click the folder >> Properties >> Security.

I clicked the "Edit" button:

[image]

I clicked "Add...":

[image]

I typed in `DIT-NB0952772\common` (which is me). I clicked "OK":

[image]

I clicked "OK":

[image]

There's an error, and I clicked **"Cancel"**:

[image]

The same screen appeared again, same error message. I clicked "Cancel" again:

[image]

Which gives me this:

[image]

It tells me to "apply the correct change immediately to achieve a consistent state",

But how do I fix this error ?

What's the correct change I should be applying to correct the errors above, and to achieve a consistent state    ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to take ownership of the folder and change the permissions to allow you to traverse the folder.

Another way to do this? My preferred method for exploring any file system without changing its state:

Explore your file system using a bootableCD.

Comment: sry I'm not understanding you. I know that I need change the permissions, but currently the problem is that I do not have permission to change the permissions, even though I'm using an admin account: http://screenshoot.me/nE5yM8

Comment: Being an admin does not mean you can change anything. The owner of the file establishes the permissions on the file. Now being an admin does allow you to **take ownership of a file**.

Comment: how do I take ownership of the file? I mean isn't checking the "Full Control" taking ownership of the file? http://screenshoot.me/nE5yM8

Comment: @Pacerier: Nope. That just **tries** to give you Full Control. Maybe I need to retype my answer more than once. . .

Comment: I mean your answers tells me to take ownership of the file.. but how do I take ownership of the file?

Comment: Besides, you are looking at the wrong spot. `C:\Users\All Users\Desktop` isn't a folder.  It's a link to `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`

Comment: Ok I'm not sure I'm understanding you.. I mean I can't edit myself to have "Full Control" for the `C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop\` folder as well, using the steps listed in the question above (right click >> Properties >> Security Tab >> Edit Button >> Add `DIT-NB0952772\common` >> Tick All >> Ok >> Access is Denied)

Comment: Do Properties, Security tab, Advanced button, Owner tab, Take Ownership button.

Answer (score 5):

You should be using C:\Users\Public\Desktop.

C:\Users\All Users\Desktop is just there for compatibility purposes and if any pre-vista program attempts to write to it, vista will re-direct to the new location.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should of asked what his end result was first.

Comment: I'm having the same error even though I'm doing the exact steps on `C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop`. http://screenshoot.me/IOw0iT in the popup I clicked cancel and I get this: http://screenshoot.me/Kdo63U

Answer (score 1):

I agree with surfasb's point. If you just want to view the contents of the folder, you don't have to change the permissions.

You can simply run a third party file manager (like total commander) tool **as Administrator** and you should be able to see the contents directly. Most will also allow you to open the Windows properties dialogue to change the permissions. Since you'll be running as Administrator, you'll not see any access denied messages.

If you don't have a third party file manager, you can run a archiving tool like WinRAR or 7-zip as admin and they should also allow you to view the contents of the folders and give you the Windows context menu somewhere.

Comment: Ok I'm aware that we can run a third party tool to see the contents of the folder but I was wondering what are the steps required to do it without third party tools